# How to change trace-id header in opentracing?

Tags: java, spring-cloud, traefik, opentracing, jaeger

Is there way to configure opentracing-spring-jaeger-cloud-starter to handle any other header than Uber-Trace-Id? I have Traefik as an ingress in my kubernetes cluster. Traefik can be configured to change traceContextHeaderName. Default value is "uber-trace-id". When I change it to some custom, there is no connection (I mean span connection) between services. I believe that opentracing works only with Uber-Trace-Id. Is there way to configure that?

I test this in minikube with Traefik as an ingress. Then all requests go to spring-cloud-gateway and are propagate to services.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no out-of-the-box possibility to change the HTTP header name.
However, you can enable B3 header propagation with `opentracing.jaeger.enable-b3-propagation=true`.
To configure Traefik to send the trace data as B3 headers, see https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/docs/content/observability/tracing/jaeger.md#propagation.
`traceContextHeaderName` should also be configured as `X-B3-TraceId` then.